# Oracle Partitioned table is taking long time to fetch

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a partioned table based on date in oracle db, where each partition has crores of records. The front end application is build to search the data based on a date range (meanining it scans through multiple partitions). What is the best logic to get the data in quickest time?

Comment: If you're looking for general principles for tuning non-specific queries against partitioned tables then the documentation is the place to look. If you have a specific performance problem then the minimum information needed is the query, the table structure (including partitioning), the execution plan, and the Oracle version.

Answer (score 1):

You should create local indexes which work on partitions.
Normally we go for global indexes which work on whole table while local index is specific to partition which will make partition search faster.

Check this link to see how local indexes work: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#i461446

If local indexes don't work then query tuning might help. If that doesn't help then you shld look to redesign schema.

EDIT:
Having said all that, just one basic check to ensure that your query is not scanning all partitions. This can be achieved by including partition criteria [date in your case] as part of where clause.

Answer (score 0):

[Interval partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE) may help.  It makes partition management much
easier, which then makes it reasonable to have thousands of partitions instead of just dozens or hundreds.

For example, if the current table is partitioned by month, a query for a week will need to read a lot of extra data.  But if the table is partitioned by day
then almost no extra data will be scanned.

```
create table partition_test(a number primary key, b date)
partition by range (b) interval (interval '1' day)
(
    partition p1 values less than (date '2000-01-01')
);
```

But even if this reduces the data per partition from crores to lakhs, that's still a lot of data for an application.  Local indexes, as @loki suggested, may help.